# dynamic array name with values

Tags: php, arrays

i have arrays as box1 box2 etc...i am trying to find the common elements/values between any 2 random arrays...but i keep getting error that target1 and target2 are not arrays below is my code:-

```
$box1=array("1","2","3","4","7","9");
$box2=array("11","2","34","4","72","9");
$box3=array("13","42","3","64","7","89");
$box4=array("71","24","38","43","7","19");
$box5=array("1","52","37","94","7","79");

$nos1=rand(1,5);
$nos2=rand(1,5);

$target1="$box".$nos1;
$target1="$box".$nos2;
$common=array();
$common=array_intersect($target1,$target2);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `$target1="$box".$nos1;`?

Comment: Please see the manual for variable variables: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Use `'$box'.$nos1` instead

Comment: and `$target2` is undefined. You may have meant to have `$target1="$box".$nos2` as `$target2="$box".$nos2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning random box to target in wrong way. Use the code below:

```
$box1=array("1","2","3","4","7","9");
$box2=array("11","2","34","4","72","9");
$box3=array("13","42","3","64","7","89");
$box4=array("71","24","38","43","7","19");
$box5=array("1","52","37","94","7","79");

$nos1=rand(1,5);
$nos2=rand(1,5);

$target1=${"box".$nos1};
$target2=${"box".$nos2};
$common=array();
$common=array_intersect($target1,$target2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @KamalPaliwal 's answer:
Another way to accomplish/write this with [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
<?php
$box1=array("1","2","3","4","7","9");
$box2=array("11","2","34","4","72","9");
$box3=array("13","42","3","64","7","89");
$box4=array("71","24","38","43","7","19");
$box5=array("1","52","37","94","7","79");

$varname1="box".rand(1,5);
$varname2="box".rand(1,5);

$target1 = $$varname1;
$target2 = $$varname2;
$common=array();
$common=array_intersect($target1,$target2);
```